# How to ask a query "Are you sure?" on the band

Tags: microsoft-band

Simple Question (I hope):

My app already has a tile on the band. If an event happens and the phone needs to ask the question "Are you sure? (Yes/No)" Is there a simple way to do this on the MS band? also get the result.

I've looked at SendMessage/SendDialog/ShowPanel. Showpanel example is the closest but I do not want to add a new Tile To band. Just ask a question and go away.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a a custom page layout that has multiple buttons.  The application pushes the page to the Tile and subscribes to the Tile button events to see which one is pressed.  See section 2.8 of the [Band SDK documentation](http://developer.microsoftband.com/Content/docs/Microsoft%20Band%20SDK.pdf).  Note: because listening for events requires an outstanding connection to the Band, the application will want to account for the case where the user doesn't respond to the prompt within a reasonable period of time.

Comment: That helped a lot thank you. but do you force it to display, with vibrate would be nice to.
Here is my example to put text on a page:

        client.getTileManager().setPages(tileId, new PageData(pageId2, 0)
                .update(new TextBlockData(12, "Answer"))
                .update(new TextButtonData(13, "Ignore")));

Answer (score 0):

```
#Here we ask if the person is sure
sure = input("Are you sure?")

if sure == "y":
    #Run your code
elif sure == "n":
    #Here the system breaks
    break
```

I am new to this so this might not be correct but I can run this in Coding    with Chrome extension